# how to count the results from the exposed filter

Tags: views

I have created the content type named candidate_profile, included fields like candidate_name, current_position_description, location , Current_Salary_Range, New_Business_Achievements and Categories_ of_Experience and I have created a view named display_candidate and also I am using better-exposed filter  for current_salary_range field hence how should I proceed to count the results from the exposed filter...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get that in the `view` itself.

```
view->Header->"Global: Result summary"
```

[image]

Comment: Please accept and upvote the answer if it is useful to you. So that others may use this.

Comment: alfer get that result and how to check the result is >20 or <20.

Comment: what does that mean by >20 or <20? please elaborate what you are looking for to get proper answer.

Comment: when the total result is less than 20 how to find related results based on the exposed filter field.

Comment: what does that mean related results?

Comment: when the search result is lesser than 20 for the exposed filter field current_salary_range 20000 i should show results for the current_salary_range above 20000.